# Is there no door-open voice intent?

Tags: bixby

When creating a new bixby home studio project on the select voice intents step there is no door-open voice intent in the door bixby voice category. Why? Closing a door works fine without ever touching bixby home studio but a voice intent for door-open doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 2):

This issue would require some more information from you.

Please reach out to the Bixby Developer Support team (bixby-support@samsung.com) with the following information.

- Name
- Email
- Use case
- Make and model of the device

This will allow the team to speak with you directly and investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

What device are you trying to control and what are you doing with it? Are you querying whether a door is open or closed? Are you trying to open or close a door? Please describe in non-BHS terms and we can point you in the right direction